# xmlnodelist to a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, xml-parsing

I am reading an xml file using xmldocument.
I extracted the nodes of xml using xmlnodelist. I would like to now assign the xmlnodelist to a list of objects "Project". Please let me know how I can do that .

```
<Projects>
  <Project>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Fabric1</Name>
  </Project>
   <Project>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Fabric2</Name>
  </Project>
</Projects>


Class :
 public class Project
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


Code :

     XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/abc.xml"));
                XmlNodeList listofProjests = xdoc.SelectNodes("/Projects/Project");
                var project = new List<Project>();

                foreach (XmlNode p in listofProjests)
                {
                    ?? = p.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText;
                    ?? = p.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
                 }
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use `XmlDocument`? If you can use LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) it's trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, you can do this trivially in LINQ to XML:

```
var projects = XDocument
    .Load(Server.MapPath("~/Content/abc.xml"))
    .Root
    .Elements("Project")
    .Select(p => new Project {
                Id = (string) p.Element("Id"),
                Name = (string) p.Element("Name")
            })
    .ToList();
```

I'd strongly advise you to use LINQ to XML rather than the old `XmlDocument` API if you can (and by now, you really should be able to... LINQ to XML has been around for a *long* time).

Of course, you *could* do it with your current code:

```
foreach (XmlNode p in listofProjests)
{
    string id = p.SelectSingleNode("Id").InnerText;
    string name = p.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText;
    project.Add(new Project { Id = id, Name = name });
}
```

or slightly more pleasantly (IMO):

```
foreach (XmlElement p in listofProjests)
{
    string id = p["Id"].InnerText;
    string name = p["Name"].InnerText;
    project.Add(new Project { Id = id, Name = name });
}
```

... but I really wouldn't.